# How can I access GMX calendar outside of web UI?

Tags: calendar, gmx

GMX provides:

- a mail service accessible through IMAP,
- a file service accessible through WebDAV,
- a calendar service.

But I've never found if there is any way of accessing that calendar service through a standard protocol (CalDAV or iCal). Is there such an access?

Answer (score 1):

From [the help pages](https://support.gmx.com/organizer/mobile/apps.html#indexlink_help_organizer_mobile):

> You can use your GMX Organizer with every application that supports the CalDAV standard or .ics format like Outlook, Thunderbird or Mac OS calendar.
>
> The GMX Organizer can be synchronized with all calendar apps that support the CalDAV standard.
>
> (...)
>
> The CalDAV address is https://caldav.gmx.com/.